# BEX error on Windows Web Server 2008 R2 x64

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, buffer-overflow

I have built an application that causes a buffer overflow exception with the following signature on Windows Web Server 2008 R2 x64

> Problem signature:
>
> > Problem Event Name:  BEX
> >
> > Application Name:    AlgorithmEvaluation.exe
> >
> > Application Version: 1.0.0.0
> >
> > Application Timestamp:   4f7c6063
> >
> > Fault Module Name:    clr.dll
> >
> > Fault Module Version: 4.0.30319.1
> >
> > Fault Module Timestamp:   4ba1d9ef
> >
> > Exception Offset: 002b5b8c
> >
> > Exception Code:   c0000409
> >
> > Exception Data:   00000000
> >
> > OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.1296.17
> >
> > Locale ID:    1033
> >
> > Additional Information 1: 5044
> >
> > Additional Information 2: 50442b9f233457091c25e076784708c8
> >
> > Additional Information 3: 3eea
> >
> > Additional Information 4: 3eeac65aee1d9241f0a9b0ca3bae03d6

The application is written in C# and calls a .NET dll (written in C++/CLI) which, in turn, wraps a native C++ dll. Since I don't have the source code for the x86 C++ dll, I have set all the other code to build as x86. The C# application is multi-threaded, using Microsoft's CCR, and it reads and writes to a SQL Server 2008 Express Database.

Following these instructions from [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2279689), I have set the C++/CLI project to be TSAWARE, and according to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2229865), I think my C# project should already be TSAWARE by default (I am accessing the Web Server machine using remote desktop, if that matters). I have also read this [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483.aspx) piece. I considered following the [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2279689) suggestion to turn off DEP, but am concerned that this could lead to something worse happening

The application causes no problems on my laptop, which is running Windows 7 Home x64.

Unfortunately I don't have the hardware to run this on my laptop in reasonable time. Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks